# Jquery Colorbox, open from input field, return value back

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

i try to fill/overwrite(if exists) an input field from an colorbox popup search form, but i dont get the variable back into my input field.

this is the mainpage:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css">
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/colorbox/colorbox.css" />

<script>
$(function() {
var kid = $('#Kontaktname').val();
$("#Kontaktname").colorbox({
    href:"contact_search_popup.php?s_contacts_id=" + kid,
    iframe:true,
    innerWidth:850,
    innerHeight:400,
    opacity:0.1,
    overlayClose:false,
    });
});
</script>

<p><input type="text" id="Kontaktname" value="1001" name="Kontaktname"></p>

<p id="test">
return value:
</p>
```

this is colorbox popup page:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css">
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/colorbox/colorbox.css" />

<input type="submit" id="formSubmit" class="test" value="{Label1}" name="formSubmit"> 

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("input.test").click(function() {
 window.parent.$("#kontaktname").text($(this).val()); // works
 window.parent.$("#test").text($(this).val());        // dont work !!!
 parent.$.colorbox.close();
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: is there any error in your console?

Comment: iam using firefox, i found some warnings, but no errors, for example, sorry for german: Zeitstempel: 18.02.2013 16:50:24
Warnung: Fehler beim Verarbeiten des Wertes für 'filter'.  Deklaration ignoriert.
Quelldatei: http://192.168.5.202/realcrm/jquery/colorbox/colorbox.css
Zeile: 68

Comment: I don't see a reason for this not to work. Could you possibly post a fiddle of this?

Comment: i found a solution:   window.parent.document.getElementById("kontaktname").value = $(this).val();